# C# how to return from linq2sql query back to main

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have been working with simple linq2sql statements for a bit but am new to using them with classes. I just want to put the linq statement in the review class and call it from the frmMain class to fill my combobox. I know it should use some properties and the code below is very wrong but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    Review r = new Review();
    r.getEmp();
    cboEmployee.DataSource = emps
}

class Review : frmMain
{
    private "return type?" getEmp()
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var emps = (from emp in db.employees
                        where emp.active == true
                        orderby emp.name
                        select emp.name.Substring(0, 20)).ToList();
            return emps;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the return type should be `List<string>` or one of the interfaces it implements.

You also need to assign the return value to something in the calling code:

```
Review r = new Review(); 
var newDataSource = r.getEmp(); 
cboEmployee.DataSource = newDataSource;
```

or simply

```
Review r = new Review(); 
cboEmployee.DataSource = r.getEmp();
```

In general, the return type of the method must be the type of the value returned from the method, or a supertype of that value.  You are returning the result of the ToList() call, so the return type of your method must be compatible with that.

In your calling code, you seem to be confused by variable scope.  The `emps` variable is a local variable of the getEmp method; it is not visible outside that method.

Because getEmp is defined in a class other than the one from which it is called, it must be `internal` or `public` so it will be visible to the calling class.  Or, just define the getEmp method in the frmMain class rather than the Review class.  Do you even need a Review class in the first place?

The first snippet above assigns the return value to another local variable (which I've called `newDataSource` to reduce the potential for confusion), and then assigns the value of that variable to `cboEmployee.DataSource`.  The second sample skips the intermediate assignment.

Comment: How can I keep the data private now with get and set?

Comment: @adam355 what data are you trying to keep private, and where are you using get and set?

Comment: Nothing yet. I thought I should keep the getEmp method private as best practice since its in a different class. Am I wrong? I am a fairly new coder

Comment: @adam355 yes, given your limited example, it makes sense to have getEmp as a private method of the frmEmp class.  However, you sometimes need to have public methods!  The oddest part of your example is that Review inherits from frmMain, and that you create a new Review instance in your frmMain class.  I note that the frmMain sample you posted doesn't compile, since two of those lines of code need to be inside a method body, but aren't.

Comment: @adam355 in general, you should think of a class as having *one job* (the "single responsibility principle").  Public members should expose the input and output of that job.  Implementation details should be private (and a task like "generate a list of strings to put in a combo box" is an implementation detail).

Comment: I am no longer inheriting from the frmClass that was a mistake. I appreciate your example. You are a lot of help. I just need to figure out how to add get set properties now as I would like to do it for best practice. This is one of my first robust applications and I would like it to be done well since I will be referencing it a lot in the future. If you could show me how to add the properties that would be wonderful.

Comment: @adam355 before you can add a get/set property, you need a class that has some value that can be gotten or set.  Do you have such a class?  Are you stuck on creating a property for it?  If so, maybe it's best to post another question.  The `getEmp` method is probably best left as a method, not a property (and a more idiomatic name would be `GetEmployeeList`, but that's another matter).

Answer (score 2):

```
private List<string> getEmp()
{
    using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
    {
        var emps = (from emp in db.employees
                    where emp.active == true
                    orderby emp.name
                    select emp.name.Substring(0, 20)).ToList();
        return emps;
    }
}
```

Then set the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox`:

```
  cboEmployee.DataSource = r.getEmp();
```

Comment: Thank You! How shall i implement properties since getEmp is inaccessible due to protection level?

Comment: @adam355 make the method public (or internal), not private.

Comment: Isnt that bad programming to make it public?

Comment: @adam355 I just realized that Review inherits from frmMain.  That seems weird.  Why did you do it?  A better solution would be to define getEmp as a private method of frmMain.

Comment: It seems weird because I am new and learning. So for that reason I have no answer.. lol Can you give an example?

Comment: @adam355 I'm assuming frmMain is the main form of your application.  When your application starts, it creates an instance of the form, and displays it.  Move the getImp method into the frmMain class.  Delete the Review class.  Your design is now simpler, but functionally equivalent.  Does it make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9161/discussion-between-phoog-and-adam355)